# Client-Server messaging gives error (Python - socket programming)

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, client-server

I am trying to write a simple client-server program using python (not python3) and whenever I type a message to send it gives me various errors such as:

*File "", line 1
    hello my name is darp
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

OR

*File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined*

OR

*File "", line 1
    hello world
              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing*

Here is the server code:

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))

    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connection from: "+str(addr))
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        print("From connected user: "+data)
        data = data.upper()
        print("Sending: "+data)
        c.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
    c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

AND here is the client code

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    message = input("-> ")
    while message != 'q':
        s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print("Recieved from server: " + data)
        message = input("-> ")
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Even though I can create this connection, the problem occurs after I type the message. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Python2 use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `raw_input` instead of `input` since `raw_input` will capture your input and convert it to the proper type. When using `input` you should add quotes around the input.

You can check this in the python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

Answer (score 0):

As far as the code is concerned, the only change you need to make here is in server code. Replace c.close() with s.close() as c is a connection variable whereas s is the socket of server according to your code.

I have made your code run, after making the change it runs as expected.I executed it in Python 3.

The server code is here:

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"       # supply different hostname instead of socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))

    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connection from: "+str(addr))
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        print("From connected user: "+data)
        data = data.upper()
        print("Sending: "+data)
        c.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
    s.close()           # it is s which indicates socket

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

And the client code is as given by you:

```
import socket

def Main():
# here, client is using the hostname whereas you need to give different 
# hostname for the server (127.0.0.1 for example) otherwise the code doesn't 
# work.You can do the reverse as well.
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    message = input("-> ")
    while message != 'q':
        s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print("Recieved from server: " + data)
        message = input("-> ")
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```